# Create an array not a variable of values taken from the dom with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im searching for elements with a class of 'some-class' within an element with a specific ID (provided by the variable myID).

For each one of these I need to get the value of the data attribute called 'data-att'. 
I then want to create an array of these but add the string `custom-class--` to the beginning of each one.

My code below works except that it only generates **1 value**. How can I make an array rather than a variable?

```
// a in the ID of the container to search in for elements with a class of 'some-class'
var myID = '#' + myID;

// Create a varialbe which starts 'custom-class--' and then has the data-att attribute
// of elements for elemts with a class of 'some-class'
var class = 'custom-class--' + $(myID).find('.some-class').attr('data-att');
```

UPDATE - here is a working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reVeja?editors=1111

```
<a href="#" class="some-class" data-att="data-1">Link</a>

<div id="my-id">
  <a href="#" class="some-class" data-att="data-2">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="some-class" data-att="data-3">Link</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

  // a in the ID of the container to search in for elemnts with a class of 'some-class'
  var myID = '#' + 'my-id';

  // Create a variable which starts 'custom-class--' and then has the data-att attribute 
  // of elements for elements with a class of 'some-class'
  var myClass = 'custom-class--' + $(myID).find('.some-class').attr('data-att');

  console.log(myClass);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add full coding of this functionality ?

Comment: @msvairam Ive updated my question.

Comment: use `.each` jQuery method to loop through the collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var myID = '#' + myID;
var elemClass=[];

$(myID).find('.some-class').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('data-att').length){ 

      elemClass.push('custom-class--'+ $(this).attr('data-att')) ;
   }

});
```

And note that you can't use `reserved words` like `class`in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to loop through the elements and create automatically a new array filled with the values you return from the map callback. In the callback I am using `data()` to get the value of the `data-att`:

```
var parentId = '#PARENTID',
    clNames = $.map( $(parentId).find('.some-class'), function( i,el ){
        return 'custom-class--'+ $(el).data('att');
    });
```

But be aware that this one will always return a value, even if you don't have an `data-att` attribute on the element. If you have cases with no `data-att` you will end up with `custom-class--undefined`. Which is not really a problem, you could use it even as a default style.